# Popup menu selected item in Toolbar

Tags: android

When I click item in popup menu its TextView background remains the same.

Screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtrGN.png

I use Toolbar:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/actionbar_height"
        app:popupTheme="@style/PopupMenu"
        app:theme="@style/Toolbar" />
```

With custom theme for Popup menu:

```
 <style name="Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:height">@dimen/actionbar_height</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/background</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="android:background">@color/background</item>
</style>
```

How to make select work properly?

Comment: And I assume you can't access the underlying `TextView`? If you can, simply put its background to transparent value at all times.

Comment: @NitroNbg I'm not sure if it's possible. I hope there is a way to solve this problem only with xml.

Comment: If you're using `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar` theme, it seems that you cannot change `popupTheme` via XML. Try changing the Theme to `Light` and try it again

Comment: @sicachester You mean `Theme.Light`? And what exactly should I change, PopupMenu theme or whole app theme?

Comment: Whole app theme... Try changing to `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light`

Comment: @sicachester It didn't help. Only overflow button went dark.

Comment: Facing the same issue and also tried ZoserLock below solution but still facing the same issue. Guys did you found anything, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and with try and error i found that using:

```
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background</item>
```

instead of

```
<item name="android:background">@color/background</item>
```

Solves the problem for me, i dont know if achieve the same result but al least does not show the uggly background.

Answer (score 1):

ColorBackground as mentioned by ZoserLock didn't work for me either I had to have

```
<item name="android:background">@color/background</item>
<item name="android:drawSelectorOnTop">true</item>
```

I also found android:backgroundTint did the same thing as background.

```
<item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/background</item>
<item name="android:drawSelectorOnTop">true</item>
```

NOTE: if you are using your own selector using selectableItemBackground and your selector isn't transparent drawSelectorOnTop won't work as it will cover your text. I'm yet to find a solution I am happy with.